# Powershell Select-String to remove a string line from a variable if matched

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to do the following:

1. Look for a file in a folder which has been modified in the past 24 hours
2. Find a specific section of the file
3. Remove lines from the section matching specific string(s)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$SummaryData = gci
| where {([datetime]::now - $_.lastwritetime).TotalHours -lt 24}
| get-content
| select-string 'SUMMARY' -context 0,10
| Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'Files updated on right side'}
```

The code above returns no objects.  However, if I remove `| Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'Files updated on right side'}` it returns the full text:

```
> SUMMARY
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  Short Results: 15 copied (203.3GB)
  Operation completed at 22:11:21 on 02/02/2013
  Total duration: 01:01:49

  Copied To Right Side: 15 (203.3GB)
  Files updated on right side : 15

  Transfer amount saved due to partial file updating : 196.2GB
  Remaining actual transfer amount for eligible files: 7.1GB
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 2):

As usually with PowerShell - what you see is not (exactly) what you get. Data that you try to check with `Where-Object` is `$_.Context.PostContext`.

Something like the following worked for me:

```
$SummaryData = Get-ChildItem | 
    where {(New-TimeSpan -Start $_.LastWriteTime).TotalHours -lt 24} | 
    select-string 'SUMMARY' -context 0,10 | 
    Where-Object {$_.Context.PostContext -notmatch 'Files updated on right side'}
```

Please, keep in mind that `$summaryData` will contain objects rather than actual text, so to get text instead you need to modify the command.

EDIT: If you want just text *and* get rid of the single line you've mentioned:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
    where {(New-TimeSpan -Start $_.LastWriteTime).TotalHours -lt 24} | 
    select-string 'SUMMARY' -context 0,10 | 
    foreach {@($_.Line) + @($_.Context.PostContext) } | 
    where { $_ -notmatch 'Files updated on right side' }
```

This builds array of strings from `$_.Line` (captured line) and `$_.Context.PostContext` (all that was captured by the `-Context` parameter), outputs as [String[]], and finally removes the element that you are after.

Comment: Thanks guys for the swift response. BartekB, I couldn't get your specific example to work. However, @Indrek yours did.  Both examples prefaced the filename and linenumber to each line for some reason.  The only obvious thing which changed was the way the date was calculated.